# Get Count of Records in Separate Column

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Table : STATUS_TABLE

```
id | Status  | 
=================
1      true
2      false
3      false
4      true
```

How can I get count of both True and False in separate column using Oracle??
I must show only those record whose status is true. So I put where condition.
But I must display count of Both.
Like

```
MARKED_RECORD  UNMARKED_RECORD
      2                2
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MARKED_RECORD,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) UNMARKED_RECORD
FROM    STATUS_TABLE
```

Comment: I must show only those record whose status is true. So I put where condition. But I must display count of Both.

Comment: @Milan, this answer gives you exactly what you asked for. Why are you adding a where condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH src1 AS
(
        SELECT 1 id, 'TRUE'  status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 id, 'TRUE'  status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 id, 'FLASE' status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 id, 'TRUE'  status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 id, 'FLASE' status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 6 id, 'TRUE'  status FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 7 id, 'FLASE' status FROM dual
)
, src AS
(
        SELECT  id
        ,       status
        ,       SUM(DECODE(status, 'TRUE',   1, NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS is_true
        ,       SUM(DECODE(status, 'FLASE',  1, NULL)) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS is_false
        FROM    src1
)
SELECT  s1.id
,       s1.status
,       s2.m_is_true
,       s2.m_is_false
FROM    src s1
CROSS   JOIN
(
        SELECT  MAX(is_true)  AS m_is_true
        ,       MAX(is_false) AS m_is_false
        FROM    src
) s2
WHERE   s1.status = 'TRUE'
;
```

Result:

```
ID       STATUS   M_IS_TRUE     M_IS_FALSE
1        TRUE     4             3        
2        TRUE     4             3        
4        TRUE     4             3        
6        TRUE     4             3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
select decode(status,'true','Marked','false','Unmarked')status, 
       count(status) Count 
from sample_table 
code layoutgroup by status
```